# How to fetch submodules in github

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, git-pull, git-fetch

I have used the following commands but submodules are not fetched :(

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/NecronomiconCoding/NecroBot

git fetch upstream

git merge upstream/master

git submodule foreach git pull upstream master
```

However the submodule `FeroxRev @ 33654cd` is not fetched into my local repository :(

So how can I fetch the latest submodule?

Here my project  : https://github.com/MonsterMMORPG/aaddd/

When I click submodule name it goes into remote repository

Answer (score 4):

If you have merge upstream/master and now have a .gitmodules declaring a FerexRev suvmodule, do first:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
# or
git submodule update --init
```

Then you can check if the submodule is present.

You can also [make that submodule follow a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33895502/6309).