# Create git branches in multiple repositories at the same time

Tags: git, github, repository, branch

I have twenty git repositories on github and I want to be able to create a branch in all the twenty repositories with one command or click (without going through to all the twenty repos manually one at a time).

I do understand that I may write a shell script to do that. I am wondering if I am able to utilize sub modules of if there is any other way? Not sure, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if still in development but you should be able to do it with https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/

Comment: What's the purpose? Do you also need to commit automatically on the 20 branches? Or is this a one time action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering you can [push to multiple repositories at one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4255934/6309), you could define in your local repo an remote "all" referencing those 20 repos, create a local orphan branch, and push that branch to "all"

If your branch is supposed to start from an existing branch, then submodules are indeed a better solution, as you might be talking about 20 different repositories, each one with their own existing history.

With a local repo referencing in a `.gitmodules` 20 repos, you can use ([as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1032653/6309)) the `git submodule foreach` syntax in order to create and push that new branch (`git checkout master; git checkout -b new_branch; git push -u origin new_branch`, wrapped in a script [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1030263/6309))

Comment: I have a similar requirements. I have 10 different repos. For every work, i need to create the same branch in all repos. Do you think submodule is better option or it will be an overhead?

Comment: @user2636464 submodule is a good option, especially with the upcoming Git 2.36: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71195953/6309 and the new `git branch --recurse-submodules` command.

Comment: Thanks and nice to see your comments after many discussions around clearcase previously :)

Comment: @user2636464 Right! From 2013 to 2019. I still answer ClearCase questions to this day, although far less frequently.

Comment: yeah. we have also moved away decomissioning all things rational onto the other tools now.