# Is it possible to checkout branches of main repository in sync with submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules, bamboo

What I want to achieve is whenever I use git checkout on my main repository for example:

```
git checkout my-branch
```

my submodules will follow my-branch instead of a detached head.

Is it possible, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those submodule repositories have a my-branch of their own, they can be [declared to follow that branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33895502/6309)

```
cd /path/to/your/parent/repo/Foo
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.bar1.branch my-branch
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.bar2.branch my-branch

git submodule update --remote
```

But that involves repeating that each time you checkout a branch in the parent repo.

[torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772039/is-it-possible-to-checkout-branches-of-main-repository-in-sync-with-submodules/43774172#comment74618182_43774172) that those submodules might have submodules of their own, hence the need for the `--recursive` option.

> You might also want to add `--recursive` and/or `--no-fetch` to your `git submodule update --remote` command.
>   Rather than individual `git config -f` operations, you might want `git submodule foreach`, again maybe with `--recursive`.

```
git submodule foreach -q --recursive 'git config -f $toplevel/.gitmodules submodule.$name.branch my_branch'
```

In multiple lines for readability:

```
git submodule foreach -q --recursive \
  'git config -f $toplevel/.gitmodules submodule.$name.branch my_branch'
```

Then you can checkout each submodule to that branch:

```
git submodule foreach -q --recursive 'branch="$(git config -f $toplevel/.gitmodules submodule.$name.branch)"; git checkout $branch'
```

In multiple lines for readability:

```
git submodule foreach -q --recursive \
  'branch="$(git config -f $toplevel/.gitmodules submodule.$name.branch)"; \
   git checkout $branch'
```

Comment: You might also want to add `--recursive` and/or `--no-fetch` to your `git submodule update --remote` command. Rather than individual `git config -f` operations, you might want `git submodule foreach`, again maybe with `--recursive`, although getting that right looks tricky.

Comment: I agree and will edit later (I am commuting) I was just proposing the beginning of a solution, mentioning the possibility of following a branch for a submodule.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I've appreciated your help however I've created a script that submodules will follow the main repositories branch.

Comment: @GilroyToledano Nice: is your script available in a gist somewhere? (https://gist.github.com/)