# Pull all submodules to a specific branch

Tags: git, git-submodules

Assume the following git structure with submodules:

```
root
|-- .gitmodules
|-- X
    |-- submodule 1
    |-- submodule 2
    ..
    |-- submodule N
```

Assume that I am working on a branch `feature_B` from the top module and I am manually creating a branch called `feature_B` in every submodule.

At some point (assume all the changes in every submodule are pushed to the remote) I need to  run some tests with the `master` topmodule, so what I do:

```
cd $TOPMODULE
git checkout master 
git pull #just to be sure
git submodule update --init --recursive --force

# do all the testing I need on master
```

The last command however has reset every submodule to the commit specified by the topmodule. Now I want to go back to `feature_B` for **every** submodule that has such branch. How can I do?

Of course I can manually `cd` into every submodule and `git checkout feature_B` but assume I have lots of submodules, or heck, even only 5, I'd love a programmatic way for doing it.

What I come up with is the following code, but I would like to know if there is a git command to do the trick

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
#set -e

cd $TOPMODULE

BRANCH_NAME=$1
SUBS=$( cat .gitmodules | grep -Po "(?<=path = )keyword.*" )
git show-ref --verify --quiet refs/heads/${BRANCH_NAME}

for SUBMODULE_PATH in ${SUBS}
do
    cd $SUBMODULE_PATH
    
    if git show-ref --verify --quiet refs/heads/${BRANCH_NAME}; then
        #echo "checkout " $BRANCH_NAME "in" $SUBMODULE_PATH 
        git checkout $BRANCH_NAME
        git pull
    else 
        echo $BRANCH_NAME "does not exist in" $SUBMODULE_PATH  
    fi
    cd - 
done
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git submodule foreach git fetch
git submodule foreach git checkout origin/feature_B
```

or if you know your feature_B updates are always "clean", they're always direct descendants of the existing tip,

```
git submodule foreach git pull --ff-only origin feature_B
```

or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33895502/1290731) to tell Git about the upstream branches.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would this command fail if `feature_B` is not a branch in one submodule?

Comment: Yes, see the linked answer for one way to configure the branches per-submodule.

Comment: So if not all the submodules have the feature branch I need, I still need to use the bash script I added in my question, or I configure each branch manually. Fair enough, I can't expect git alone to cover all possible scenarios. Thanks!

Comment: Another way is to configure the fetch spec in each submodule to map the upstream branch you want to a particular tracking ref.